# Magento Website not working

Tags: magento-1.9

My website www.glocalshopper.com based on magento 1.9.2.4 is not working. Please view the screenshot :
http://prntscr.com/kfujg3

Following error is been provided in screenshot.Can somebody guide me how to reolve this error.
Awaiting for the right solution.

Comment: Did you something change recently ?

Comment: disable compiler and check it

Comment: Maybe this answer will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/23215331/9332214

Comment: It seems a store id issue. Did you do some changes related to the store , recently ?

Comment: Yes, I had made changes to Manage Store view, since had four store views. Two I had disabled and the other two store were enabled. Since the magneto admin panel is also showing the same error. Kindly guide me.

Comment: I cannot disable compiler check, since magento admin panel is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if that function exists in the referenced file, but it appears to be pulling a null from somewhere. However, that error generally revolves around caching. Clear your caches and if you have memcache (or something else), clear that or disable it to see if that helps.

Also might help if you stated any recent changes you made. Did you install any extensions? Remove any? Patch the site?

Comment: I had cleared all the caches several time but the same error is coming again and again. How to disable the cache ?? Kindly guide me

Comment: I had not installed any extension.

Comment: Do you use any external caching such as memcache, Redis, Varnish, etc?

Comment: I did not use any external caching.

Comment: Ia anyone Who Can Help me in this ?

Answer (score -2):

Go to file 'app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php' and on line 722

replace it

```
return $this->_stores[$this->_groups[$group]->getDefaultStoreId()]->getCode();
```

replace by

```
if(is_object($this->_stores[$this->_groups[$group]->getDefaultStoreId()])){
return $this->_stores[$this->_groups[$group]->getDefaultStoreId()]->getCode();
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't change the core files :)

Comment: By this you will be sure and find error solved or not may be new error you will found that was exact cause.

Comment: I had done the process but it too did not working. After replacing the code with yours, the 400 error was coming to the site.

Comment: Rule number one: It is forbidden to update Magento Core.